# Breeze change DenseMatrix using vector decomposition

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

Code below generates a 0-1 matrix, changes every odd row and composes a new matrix. I want to concat the vectors using `foldLeft` but I get `Not all matrices have the same number of columns`, probably because zero (or unit) element of `foldLeft` is an empty vector of unknown size.

```
import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.stats.distributions._
object ZeroOneMatrix {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val n = 4
    val m = DenseMatrix.rand[Int](n, n, rand = Rand.randInt(2))
    println(m)

    // vs is of type Vector[DenseVector[Int]]
    val vs = for (r <- 0 until n)
      yield {
        if (r % 2 == 1)
          m(r, ::).t map (e => (e + 1) % 2)
        else m(r, ::).t
      }
    println(vs)

    // compose matrix back from the list of vectors vs
    val f = (vs foldLeft DenseVector[Int]().asDenseMatrix)(
        (mat, v) => DenseMatrix.vertcat(v.asDenseMatrix, mat))
    println(f)
  }
}
```

How could it be fixed? Also why `map` can not be called on `m(r, ::)` without doing transponation? Ideally I would map a chosen vector into a new one and then would use `DenseMatrix.horzcat` to build the matrix.

The reason of not using the `map` function on entire matrix is that some rows are not going to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about why it's not working. Why not just use `reduce`? Or: `DenseVector.vertcat(vs:_*)`

Map: Breeze privileges column vectors, and a lot of functionality is missing for row vectors. In general, you should probably get in the habit of working with columns rather than rows.

Comment: Thank you for hints. When I use `reduce`, it says `mat` is `DenseVector` while required `DenseMatrix`, so I convert `mat.asDenseMatrix` and then it fails on `v.asDenseMatrix` requiring `DenseVector` :)

Comment: `DenseVector.vertcat(vs:_*)` is not working as I need a matrix in the end and this gives me a joined vector. What I'm doing is transforming a matrix from one state to another by changing some of the rows in it. And I do not want to mutate the matrix and achieve it in a functional style by using a `map`.

Comment: About applying `map` only to columns. Why is that? Matrices are symmetric and rows should be treated evenly as columns. Multiplying rows by a constant and subtracting them is the basis of Gaussian elimination algorithm which reduces a matrix to the Entity matrix.

Comment: Final solution - `DenseMatrix.vertcat(vs:_*)`

Comment: Ah, so, `mat(*, ::).map( )` should do what you want. DenseVectors have a shape, which is a column vector (since Breeze is column major), and I never really fleshed out the transpose of that. I'm starting to, but it'll be a while.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. One more please: if I use `mat(*, ::).map(e => (e + 1) % 2)`, can I somehow in the code of map function access `e.row` or `e.column` (because my function depends on that information)?

Comment: nope, sorry. i agree it would be nice to have. You can open an issue on github